# I am trying to make a game of snake in HTML 5. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

Nothing is showing up on the screen. This is what I have so far:

In index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="480" style="background-color:grey;"></canvas>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In script.js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var player = {
    x1: 30,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 20,
    y2: 0,
    x3: 10,
    y3: 0,
    x4: 0,
    y4: 0,
    width: 10,
    height: 10
}

var keys = [];
var speed = 10;

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);


function update(){
    if(keys[37]){
        if(!(player.x1 = 0)){
            if(!(player.x2 = player.x1 - player.width)){
                player.x4 = player.x3;
                player.y4 = player.y3;
                player.x3 = player.x2;
                player.y3 = player.y2;
                player.x2 = player.x1;
                player.y2 = player.y1;
                player.x1 -= player.width;
            }
        }
    }
    if(keys[39]){
        if(!(player.x1 = canvas.width - player.width)){
            if(!(player.x2 = player.x1 + player.width)){
                player.x4 = player.x3;
                player.y4 = player.y3;
                player.x3 = player.x2;
                player.y3 = player.y2;
                player.x2 = player.x1;
                player.y2 = player.y1;
                player.x1 += player.width;
            }
        }
    }
    if(keys[38]){
        if(!(player.y1 = 0)){
            if(!(player.y2 = player.y1 - player.height)){
                player.x4 = player.x3;
                player.y4 = player.y3;
                player.x3 = player.x2;
                player.y3 = player.y2;
                player.x2 = player.x1;
                player.y2 = player.y1;
                player.y1 -= player.height;
            }
        }
    }
    if(keys[40]){
        if(!(player.y1 = canvas.height - player.height)){
            if(!(player.y2 = player.1 + player.height)){
                player.x4 = player.x3;
                player.y4 = player.y3;
                player.x3 = player.x2;
                player.y3 = player.y2;
                player.x2 = player.x1;
                player.y2 = player.y1;
                player.y1 += player.height;
            }
        }
    }
}

function render(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(player.x1, player.y1, player.width, player.height);
    context.fillRect(player.x2, player.y2, player.width, player.height);
    context.fillRect(player.x3, player.y3, player.width, player.height);
    context.fillRect(player.x4, player.y4, player.width, player.height);
}

function gameLoop(){
    update();
    render();
}

setInterval(function(){
    gameLoop();
}, 500);
```

I hope you can tell what I am trying to do with this code. Please ask any necessary question. In order to be able to post this, I need a lot of more words to count for the code. This paragraph will be repeated.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you have any errors in your console? Try to isolate the code you are having problems with.

Comment: Instead of those filling words you could have described your problem, written any error message logged in the console, described what you have tried to solve the problem yourself, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to _compare_ `player.y1 - player.height` to `player.y2` (and similar) in those `if` statements instead of _assign_ to it?

Comment: You should use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) next time to debug the code yourself, before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The console mentions

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

here

```
if(keys[40]){
    if(!(player.y1 = canvas.height - player.height)){
        if(!(player.y2 = player.1 + player.height)){
```

change to

```
if(keys[40]){
    if(!(player.y1 = canvas.height - player.height)){
        if(!(player.y2 = player.y1 + player.height)){
```